# Create and configuring Application Pool on IIS w10 and powershell 7.2

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to create a pool of applications with specific parameters using this code:

```
    $currentAppPool = New-WebAppPool -Name myNeyAppPool
    
    # Set pool specifications
    $currentAppPool.AutoStart = "true"
    $currentAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "No Managed Code"
    
    $currentAppPool | Set-Item
```

I have several errors because setitem asks me for a path variable that it doesn't recognize. Set-Item: The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  Path

I tried to give it the parameter -path IIS:\AppPools\myNeyAppPool but I get the message
Set-Item: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist

There are quite a few changes concerning the management of IIS in w10 via powershell 7, but little documentation seems to exist on the subject.

Is there anything help ?

Thks,

Comment: You are using an Alias path name.  Is drive on machine or a Network Drive?  If Network drive than start path with two backslashes.  If local it is probably the c:\ drive.  You may need to run PS as an admin by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The provider "IIS:" is loaded when importing the webadministration module.

[Providers before and after to load webadministration module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpOII.png)

Do you have IIS role enabled in windows 10?
You can check the following link:
https://community.lansweeper.com/t5/installation/how-to-install-iis-internet-information-services/ta-p/64422

Which providers appear if you run the "Get-PSProvider" command?

Answer (score 0):

First try running PowerShell as an administrator, and then the drive is provided by the WebAdministration module, so you need make sure install that module, you can install the module with the following PowerShell commands:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Scripting-Tools
```